# OpenAI GPT-3 API error: "That model does not exist"

Tags: node.js, openai-api, gpt-3

Get "That model does not exist" from api call in node.js

```
const chatGptUrl = "https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/chat-gpt/jobs";

...

const response = await axios.post(
      chatGptUrl,
      {
        prompt,
        max_tokens: 100,
        n: 1,
        stop: "",
      },
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Authorization": `Bearer ${chatGptApiKey}`,
        },
      }
    );

    const responseText = response.data.choices[0].text;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problem

You didn't set the `model` parameter. You have to set the `model` parameter to any OpenAI model that is compatible with the [Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/completions-api) endpoint. It's a required parameter. See the official [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create).

[image: Screenshot 1]

#### Solution

Set the `model` parameter. You can choose between the following models:

- `gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct`
- `babbage-002`
- `davinci-002`
- `text-davinci-003`
- `text-curie-001`
- `text-babbage-001`
- `text-ada-001`

---

Also, all [Engines endpoints](https://platform.openai.com/docs/deprecations/2022-06-03-legacy-endpoints) are deprecated.

[image: Screenshot 2]

Use the [Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/completions-api) endpoint.

Change the URL from this...

```
https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/chat-gpt/jobs
```

...to this.

```
https://api.openai.com/v1/completions
```

Comment: ok, thanks. it was chat gtp that wrote that code initially :|

Answer (score 0):

use

```
model='gpt-3.5-turbo'
```

Or any other from the list, as per your access and requirements.

Ref. *https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/overview*